# getting Index Error while accessing numpy array values using slicing

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np 
demo_matrix=np.array(([13,35.74,48],[23,37,37,38],[73,39,93,39]))

demo_matrix[2,3]
```

I'm getting Index Error when I tried to run this code.
Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to Data Science Stack Exchange. Your question is far from respecting the rules to be accepted on the website. Check [ThisLink](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to ask a question here

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to correct this

1. you passed three lists to np.array, and there are not all same size

`demo_matrix = np.array(([13,35,74,48],[23,37,37,38],[73,39,93,39]))`

```
demo_matrix[2,3] 
#demo_matrix (list of lists)
array([[13, 35, 74, 48],
       [23, 37, 37, 38],
       [73, 39, 93, 39]])
```

you used 35.74, I guess it might be typing mistake

2. If you think you are passing list values correctly
   use below code

   `demo_matrix[2][3]`

if passed lists have different sizes
then output array will be array of lists

```
array([list([13, 35.74, 48]), list([23, 37, 37, 38]),
       list([73, 39, 93, 39])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad it helped you. So can accept the answer?